# TypeError: crypto.createPrivateKey is not a function

Tags: node.js, npm, cryptojs

I am running into this error when trying to login with node. 
error:

```
TypeError: crypto.createPrivateKey is not a function
```

When I researched it appears that I need to be on version v.11.+ of node, not v.10.+ However, when I upgrade to node 11, the error is still there. I have uninstalled node completely, cleared npm cache, and reinstalled... yet that didn't work either.

```
export const InitializeJWT = async (): Promise<void> => {
  const password = crypto.pseudoRandomBytes(25).toString('base64');
  const salt = crypto.pseudoRandomBytes(25).toString('base64');
  jwtPayloadKey = crypto.scryptSync(password, salt, 32);
  jwtPayloadIv = crypto.randomBytes(16);
  const rsaKeys = crypto.generateKeyPairSync('rsa', {
    modulusLength: 2048,
    publicKeyEncoding: {
      type: 'spki',
      format: 'pem',
    },
    privateKeyEncoding: {
      type: 'pkcs8',
      format: 'pem',
      cipher: 'aes-256-cbc',
      passphrase: password,
    },
  });
  jwtSign.privateKey = crypto.createPrivateKey({
    key: rsaKeys.privateKey,
    format: 'pem',
    type: 'pkcs8',
    passphrase: password,
  });
  jwtSign.publicKey = crypto.createPublicKey({
    key: rsaKeys.publicKey,
    format: 'pem',
    type: 'spki',
  });
  debug('JWT Keys Initialized: ', password);
};
```

Has anyone ran into this error before? 
I am on node version 11.3.0 and npm version is 6.4.1

Comment: "Added in: v11.6.0" [Docs](https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#crypto_crypto_createprivatekey_key)

Answer (score 4):

I ran into this problem when writing an Electron app. Even though I have NodeJS v12 installed, Electron bundles its own version of NodeJS, which in my case was much older. For anyone using Electron, from the developer tools console, this information is in `process.version` for NodeJS, and `process.versions` for other bundled components, including the version of Electron itself.

To address your immediate question, Yuri Tarabanko has the correct answer. You say you are using Node version 11.3, the docs state that `createPrivateKey` was added in 11.6.0: https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#crypto_crypto_createprivatekey_key

Comment: Thanks for your comment. It turns out that my node-sass was not compatible with the upgraded node version. I had to upgrade to node-sass v4.13.0 for node v13.2.0... Then I had to reinstall Xcode to v10.1, but this wasn't capable with my operating system which was macOS High Sierra. So, all in all, I had to download the most recent operating System being macOSCatalina... install Xcode v10.1, clean up with CleanMyMac X and reinstall node. This finally fixed my problem.