# crypto.createPrivateKey is not a function in a next.js app

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, typescript, next.js

In my next.js app i use the function createPrivateKey from the crypto module from node.js
as stated in this thread: [TypeError: crypto.createPrivateKey is not a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59166307/typeerror-crypto-createprivatekey-is-not-a-function)
it says the function got added in  v11.6.0 but when I run `npx next info` i get:

```
Operating System:
  Platform: win32
  Arch: x64
  Version: Windows 10 Pro N
Binaries:
  Node: 16.16.0
  npm: N/A
  Yarn: N/A
  pnpm: N/A
Relevant packages:
  next: 13.0.6
  eslint-config-next: 13.0.6
  react: 18.2.0
  react-dom: 18.2.0
```

createPrivateKey doc:

https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#crypto_crypto_createprivatekey_key

how I call the function:

```
  const [privateKey, setPrivateKey] = useState("");
  const [publicKey, setPublicKey] = useState("");

  useEffect(() => {
    // Create a private key object from the private key
    const _privateKey = createPrivateKey({
      key: privateKey,
      format: "pem",
      type: "pkcs1",
    } as PrivateKeyInput);

    // Export the private key as a public key
    const publicKey = _privateKey.export({
      type: "spki",
      format: "pem",
    });

    console.log("Private key:", privateKey);
    console.log("Public key:", publicKey.toString("hex"));
    setPublicKey(publicKey.toString("hex"));
  }, [privateKey]);
```

Comment: This solution https://stackoverflow.com/a/75085010/8138591 might help you

Comment: wanna post it as an answer so i can accept it?

Comment: @Obrine Thank you very much, I have re-posted the answer here with some changes.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Generating UUID in react using crypto api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71127816/generating-uuid-in-react-using-crypto-api)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pre-rendering process of Next.js is as follow:

1. Next.js pre-renders your React page component on the server (represented as the `NextPage` type in TypeScript), so you need to add `import crypto from 'crypto'; crypto.randomUUID()` to generate a unique id on the server.
2. After the HTML page is returned to the browser as a result of pre-rendering, you need to use `window.crypto.randomUUID()` because `crypto.randomUUID()` is from the Node.js package in the server environment, not in the browser. U can add the following check to your code:

```js
// The following Node.js package is imported on the server-side 
// and not available in the browser
import crypto from 'crypto';

// Use the web browser Crypto API if you're on the client, 
// otherwise use the Node.js Crypto API on the server
typeof window !== 'undefined' ? window.crypto.randomUUID() : crypto.randomUUID()
```

See [Safely Accessing Web APIs](https://nextjs.org/docs/migrating/from-create-react-app#safely-accessing-web-apis) on the Next.js doc to learn more.

Node.js and web browsers have some APIs with the same names [^1], which cause conflict in your Next.js app. Therefore, you need to be explicit and specific about which environment (Node.js or browsers) the APIs belong to.

[^1]: This might be because both [Chrome and Node.js use the same V8 JavaScript engine](https://v8.dev/) under the hood, so they share some API interfaces